# Should I use the "with" statement in generated code?

Tags: javascript, code-generation

I am developing a programming language which compiles to javascript, the code generated contains too much repetition, like:

```
cls.$init = function(){
    this.property1 = {};
    this.anotherProperty = [1, 2, 3, 4];
    this.yetAnotherProperty = "test";
    /* etc */
}
```

This could be made much smaller (in that case, when initializing many properties), using a `with` statement:

```
cls.$init = function(){
    with(this){
        property1 = {};
        anotherProperty = [1, 2, 3, 4];
        yetAnotherProperty = "test";
        /* etc */
    }
}
```

But the question is... should I use `with` statements in generated code? (Which is not meant to be modified later)

Comment: according to this video on [googletechtalks](http://youtu.be/hQVTIJBZook) it will have a performance hit on your script

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `with` statement is going away in the next ECMAScript standard when using strict mode, so I would get used to not using it.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Strict_mode#Simplifying_variable_uses

Comment: You must mean "in the *current* ECMAScript standard", right? ;)

Comment: ECMAScript 5 is the one I mean. :)

Answer (score 3):

Why are you worried about repetition in auto-generated code?  It will likely be compressed away when gzipped and adding a `with` incurs overhead at runtime.  Douglas Crockford also says it is going away: http://www.yuiblog.com/blog/2006/04/11/with-statement-considered-harmful/#comment-586082